# How to populate ComboBox and TextBox with text from a text file

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to vba and donot know much coding in vba. 
Ive created a form in an excel workbook that contains a comboBox named `ComboBox1`and a textBox named `TextBox1`.

And I have a text file that contains the following text:

> Organisation1|taxid001
>   Organisation2|taxid002
>   Organisation3|taxid003
>   Organisation4|taxid004

Here OrganisationX refers to Organisation name and taxidXXX refers to Tax ID of the corresponding organisation.

When I load the form, `ComboBox1` should get filled with Organisation names and when I click on a particular item in the combobox containg the organization name, the corresponding Tax ID must get filled in `Textbox1`.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()

Dim File As Integer
Dim NextLine As String
File = FreeFile
Open "C:\Users\...\Documents\test.txt" For Input As File
While Not EOF(File)
  Line Input #File, NextLine
  UserForm1.ComboBox1.AddItem NextLine
Wend
Close File

End Sub
```

and to display text in TextBox1 :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim MyPos
MyPos = InStr(1, ComboBox1.Value, "|")

TextBox1.Value = " " & Right(ComboBox1.Value, MyPos - 1)
End Sub
```